# How to build map of classes in my application?

Tags: java

I want to order my application for documention. this any tool that in java that support in this?

I know and use java doc. I want to "draw" my application. to see all the connections and "tree" of classes between them. Do anybody know if this option is exsists in any Ide or platform?

Comment: what IDE are you using (if any)?

Comment: Most IDE make it easier to add javadocs and check them for completeness.

Comment: Are you also aware that every javadoc page has a "Tree" link at the top?  It only shows a tree of classes for a single package, so I don't know if that will meet your needs.

Answer (score 1):

You can use eclipse(or any other IDE) to Java doc your methods and classes, and when you want to document it si,ply go to Project - Genereate javadoc

Answer (score 0):

Do you probably mean javadoc? In this case add special comments to your classes and methods that start with `/**` instead of regular `/*` and then use command line utility `javadoc` or higher level tools provided by `ant`, maven or other build tools.